# How to pause creating new threads until older threads have ended

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, asynchronous

### Background

I have a very large binary data file (20+ GB) that I need to parse, process the data, then write my output. I have very little experience working with such large amounts of data, and while I'm having a little trouble conceptualizing how to deal with it, I do have an idea. Note: The input data contains a number of records retrieved from an IBM mainframe, so it is formatted like so:

The first 4 bytes of each record (row/line) is the RDW (record descriptor word). The RDW contains the length of the record (including the RDW). Because of the RDWs, even though the file is one constant stream of bytes, I do know where each record ends. I could translate this binary file into a text file, converting each two bytes to its hexadecimal representation, and also include a new line character at the end of the record, but I'm afraid how large a 20+ GB binary file would be if translated like that.

Because I want to leave the file as a binary file, I have one idea how to proceed:

1. Read the file sequentially using one "master" thread.
2. Once the master has reached the end of a record (using the information found in the RDW), it spawns a new "worker" thread, passing the thread the data it read from the file.

   - The worker thread parses the data, processes the data, and outputs it somewhere. (I'm thinking I'll house the data in a SQLite database.)
3. While the worker thread is working, the master thread continues reading the file, and when it finishes reading another record, it spawns a second worker thread to work on the second record. This continues until all records have been processed.

### Problem

Unfortunately, I envision a problem. The reading "master" thread will be working so much faster than the threads it spawns that I'm afraid too many threads will be created. To prevent this, I imagined this solution (in pseudocode):

```
record = file.ReadRecord()
if(numberOfRunningWorkerThreads < MAX_THREADS)
    SpawnWorkerThread(record);
else
    WaitUntil(numberOfRunningWorkerThreads < MAX_THREADS)
```

However, I have no idea how to implement such functionality, especially that last `else` condition. I'm new to multithreading and asynchrony, and I'm not even sure what the difference between those two terms is.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why not have your "Master" thread put the data into a queue.  Have a set number of worker threads that each pull from the queue.  You will have to make sure the queue is synchronized so that two worker threads will not dequeue the same data.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for a Semaphore (Or perhaps SemaphoreSlim may work for you as well). A semaphore "Limits the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently."  The Semaphore is created with a specific number of slots. Then, you can call "WaitOne" to wait for an available slot, and "Release" when done with a slot. If there are no slots available, "WaitOne" can either wait forever, or until a timeout occurs.

So in your case, the main thread would call WaitOne to wait for an available slot. Then, in at the end of the worker threads, you could call Release to free up a slot.

The .NET Semaphore:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx

.NET SemaphoreSlim (lightweight semaphore):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This sounds like _precisely_ what I'm looking for! Thank you very much! I'm going to hold off on marking this as an answer until I've read more into Semaphore and SemaphoreSlim.

Comment: @JDCAce, It's precisely what you _asked_ for, but it's not the best solution to your problem. Creating and destroying threads has a cost, and that cost probably is more than you want to pay if you create and destroy one thread for every record in the file.  If you want no more than _N_ threads to run at the same time, then your program should create _N_ threads up-front, and then re-use them.  That's what a _thread pool_ does for you (seeuser270576's answer).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how the thread pool works, but it was my understanding that it is not meant for long running tasks - which may or may not be the case here. My second thought is how many threads could be queued at a time if the main thread was much faster than the worker threads. I'm not sure if there are any limitations to the queue or resources it could hold.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution1:**

Use [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx). Set [MaxThreads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx), which

> Sets the number of requests to the thread pool that can be active concurrently. All requests above that number remain queued until thread pool threads become available.

Something like:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 1000);
// inside loop
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessRequest);
// end loop
```

Where `ProcessRequest` is your method that does the work.

**Solution2:**

If you know number of records: use `Parallel.For` and set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` accordingly.

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
i => { 
    ProcessRequest(i);
});
```

Comment: Parallel.ForEach may also be an option that doesn't require the number of records to be known, as long as they can create an enumerator that reads record by record.

Comment: @wiz true that!